# Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.4, which is older than the API version 1.5?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

I'm getting this error while trying to build a release version of my app. I'm not using kotlin dependencies so can someone tell me how I can fix this, please?

Error Log:

> Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.4, which is older than the API version 1.5. Consider using the runtime of version 1.5, or pass '-api-version 1.4' explicitly to restrict the available APIs to the runtime of version 1.4. You can also pass '-language-version 1.4' instead, which will restrict not only the APIs to the specified version, but also the language features
> w: /Users/meggan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.4.32/3546900a3ebff0c43f31190baf87a9220e37b7ea/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.32.jar:

My build.gradle (app):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }

}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs "en"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Google Design & Support Dependency
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'

    // Layout Libs
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:2.0.0@aar'

    // Connectivity Libs
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

    // OneSignal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'

}
```

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'

        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: i think usually any time you see something under a `caches` folder `(.gradle/caches/)`, you can try a clean and then rebuild as well, as this will recreate all files located there as well

Answer (score 12):

Fixed it simply by running **Invalidate Caches / Restart** on Android Studio!

Comment: if this doesn't work for some reason, navigate to `.gradle/caches/ ` folder, close android studio and manually delete this folder

Comment: Interesting, it ds not help on CircleCI though :(

Answer (score 2):

I've just change the Gradle Project Script build.gradle

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.32'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: works for us, Thank you